# How to extract values from json array in php the right way

Tags: php, arrays, json, extract, associative-array

I am trying to extract the values of the below list of arrays from JSON which does not work for me as I have tried **json_decode** in all options and checked all the random answers in this forum no one seems to match my problem.

here is my tried code

```
$someArray = json_decode($result, true);
 print_r($someArray);
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["account_number"]  .', '.$value["account_name"] "<br>";
  }
```

here is the result from the above code

```
Array ( [status] => 1 [message] => Account number resolved [data] => Array ( [account_number] => 20640888125 [account_name] => John Doe [bank_id] => 18 ) )

Warning: Illegal string offset 'account_name' in C:\xampp\htdocs\apks\bankre.php on line 24
A
```

I can't actually get each value seperately
I know am not doing something right, what am i missing?

Comment: I think you could loop `$someArray["data"]`

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to index into values which are not an array as *status* is `1` and *message* is `Account number resolved`.

If you want to print the  array for the key *data* you don't have to index but you could just print the key and the value:

```
foreach ($someArray["data"] as $key => $value) {
    echo $key . ', ' . $value . "<br>";
}
```

Output

```
account_number, 20640888125
account_name, John Doe
bank_id, 18
```

See a demo https://3v4l.org/0flvj

To access the values by indexing, you could first check if it is an array:

```
foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo $value["account_number"] . ', ' . $value["account_name"] . "<br>";
    }
}
```

See another demo https://3v4l.org/lpEtW

Comment: You did great... worked like magic, thanks to all of you @the-fourth-bird